# Update variable on *ngFor Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular8

I have a `*ngFor` and I'm trying to update a `{{subtotal}}` label on click but it updates all of the items with same value. Same goes with `{{quantity}}`. There is a way to create local variables ?
Heres my code

html

```
 <CardView class="cardStyle" *ngFor="let card of shoppingCart; let i = index;">

  <Label text="{{card?.product.productName}}" textWrap="false" class="product-title " row="1" col="0"></Label>

  <Label text="Quantity:{{quantity}}" textWrap="true" col="1" row="2" class="product-quantia" ></Label>

  <Label text="subtotal:{{subtotal}}" textWrap="true" col="1" row="2" class="product-quantia" ></Label>

  <Button text="&#xf056;" class="item-share-shop-save" (tap)="increase(card, i)" ></Button>

 </CardView>
```

my ts component

```
 subtotalResult:any = null;
 quantity: any;

increase(card:any, id:number){

   card.quantity += 1;
   this.subtotalResult = card.quantity * card.unitPrice; 

}
```

Comment: Are there any inputs to update the subtotal on the page?

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward no just the thw user click increase update the number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `quantity` and `subtotalResult` as a global item, changing for 1 item is modifying all.

Make them array if each items.

Try like this:

HTML:

```
<Label text="Quantity:{{quantity[i]}}" textWrap="true" col="1" row="2" class="product-quantia" ></Label>

<Label text="subtotal:{{subtotal[i]}}" textWrap="true" col="1" row="2" class="product-quantia" ></Label>
```

Typescript:

```
 subtotalResult: any[] = [];

  increase(card: any, index: any) {

    card.quantity += 1;
    this.subtotalResult[index] = card.quantity * card.unitPrice;

  }
```

Forked [stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11j1on)

Comment: this.quantity[index] = card.quantity throw this error  `Cannot create property 'undefined' on number '1'`

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz with demo data.It well be easier to write the code

Comment: Inyour HTML u forgot to add `;let i = index`. It should be `*ngFor="let card of shoppingCart;let i = index"`

Comment: was my bad the variable was beeing called inside a foreach loop, thanks

Comment: i noticed  if u increase the 2 item first thew item  one disapears https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bspnct

Comment: Modified answer. You had 2 conditions to display quantity, lfor less than 1 and 1 greater than 1. You should have same logic thoughout

Comment: For ( >1), u were displaying from array and for (<1) u were displaying card.quantity. So both did't match. Now I have modified the answer so that every time it displays card.quantity

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is better to do with a reactive form BUT since you have no input fields you can get away with keeping it a template driven form.

On the creation of "shoppingCart" I'm assuming from your api, you need to loop through each item in the array and ensure there is a value for quantity and subtotal to begin with ie `quantity:0` and `subtotal:0` for each item. Then the below template will work:

```
<CardView class="cardStyle" *ngFor="let card of shoppingCart; let i = index;">

  <Label text="{{card?.product.productName}}" textWrap="false" class="product-title " row="1" col="0"></Label>

  <Label text="Quantity:{{card?.quantity}}" textWrap="true" col="1" row="2" class="product-quantia" ></Label>

  <Label text="subtotal:{{card?.subtotal}}" textWrap="true" col="1" row="2" class="product-quantia" ></Label>

  <Button text="&#xf056;" class="item-share-shop-save" (tap)="increase(card, i)" ></Button>

 </CardView>
```

Then in your increase function:

```
increase(card: any, index: any) {

    shoppingCart[index].quantity += 1;
    shoppingCart[index].subtotal = card.subtotal * card.quantity 

  }
```

You always need to update "shoppingCart" because before you were just updating a reference which isn't going to do anything since your template is based on "shoppingCart".